# Spring Boot MongoDB the field with version annotation does not increment

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, optimistic-locking

This question asked several times before, but the answers in these questions didn't work for me.

This is my Book document

```
@Document
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Book
{
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed
    private String name;
    private Double price;
    private Integer stock;
    @Version
    private Integer version;

    public Book(String name, Integer stock, Double price)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.stock = stock;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

This is my bookRepository implementation

```
public interface BookRepository extends MongoRepository<Book, String>
{
}
```

And this is my customBookRepository implementation

```
@Repository
public class CustomBookRepository
{
    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public CustomBookRepository(BookRepository bookRepository)
    {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    public Book save(Book book)
    {
        return bookRepository.save(book);
    }

    public Optional<Book> findById(String id)
    {
        return bookRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public boolean updateQuantity(Integer stock, String id)
    {
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("_id", new ObjectId(id)); // (1)

        BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();
        newDocument.put("stock", stock); // (2)

        BasicDBObject updateObject = new BasicDBObject();
        updateObject.put("$set", newDocument); // (3)

        final UpdateResult book = mongoTemplate.getCollection("book").updateOne(query, updateObject);
        return book.wasAcknowledged();
    }
}
```

The version does not change, it stays 0 at my every update on the entities. (for inst. updateQuantity())

I've tried adding annotation @EnableMongoAuditing

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class ReadingIsGoodApplication
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(ReadingIsGoodApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

It doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a "custom repository"

Use jpa methods to save/update. Then the version field will be updated.